# Wso2 Identity Server Version 5.3.0 OAuth Client Key

Tags: wso2, devops, wso2-identity-server

I`m trying to automate the following process. Currently i am adding roles to existing user (Users and Roles -> list -> user -> Assign Roles), after that I go to Service Providers -> add -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration and send created OAuth Client Key and OAuth Client Secret to requester. 
Is there any way to automate all this process or is there any API's or app for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use SOAP API for this flow.

For role management, you can use RemoteUserStoreManager and for Service Provider IdentityApplicationManagementService,  you can found more information in this documentation:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+the+Service+Provider+API
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Managing+User+Stores+with+APIs